# Halachic extension of the Giving of the Torah and marriage analogy

Tags: marriage, midrash, kabbalat-hatorah, drush, allegory-mashal

The sages frequently liken the Giving of the Torah at Mount Sinai to a *chuppah* (wedding ceremony), where *Hashem* is symbolized by the *chosson* (groom) and the *Knesses Yisroel* is symbolized by the *kallah* (bride).

In a similar analogy, the Sages liken the construction of the Golden Calf to adultery under the wedding canopy. In similar spirit, a *midrash* quoted by Rav Moshe Shapiro, brings that the 2nd commandment on the First Tablet (prohibition of idolatry) corresponds to the 2nd commandment on the Second Tablet (prohibition of adultery).

In this spirit, if we were to continue the analogy, there is a *halacha* that a woman who cheats on her husband becomes prohibited both to the husband and to the one she cheated with, and her husband must give her a divorce. If that is so, why didn't *Hashem* have to divorce us, G-d forbid?

I thought to answer following the *Maharal* in the introduction to *Ohr Chadash* where he writes that one of the reasons *Hashem* forced us to accept the Torah was to "tie His hands behind His back" so-to-speak -- since a rapist who rapes a girl, if she desires, must marry her and he can never divorce her again.

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work in our case. The rapist has a *lo taaseh* (negative commandment) not to divorce and an *oseh* (positive commandment) to divorce, and it appears, if a wife were to cheat on a rapist, he has an obligation to give her a divorce.

Is there ability to halachically extend/justify this analogy?
Thank you very much.

**UPDATE**

Surprisingly, this question has been closed and marked as a duplicate of [another question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/83739/remarrying-hashem-after-divorce), which seems to address a different issue. That question asks how it was possibly for Him to remarry us again, my question questions how the analogy is appropriate altogether.

None of the answers given there address any of the issues brought out in this question.

Comment: My understanding (no source, sorry) is that even if a rapist's wife commits adultery, he is not permitted to divorce her.

Comment: That's why the Midrash says that Moshe broke the Luchot. See Rashi to Shemot 34:1 -- Also see http://www.sichosinenglish.org/books/chassidic-dimension-5/54.htm and http://www.nachumsegal.com/taking-a-closer-look-at-parshas-ki-sisa-with-rabbi-dov-kramer/

Comment: @yoel I find that very surprising.

Comment: It could be that Biblically the husband is able to keep the wife. It is just that the Rabbis made a penalty as a deterrent from committing adultery.

Comment: @Emetv'Shalom do youhave a source for that? if yes, please write it up as an answer and i will accept it

Comment: @gt6989b +1 for a thought-provoking question. what if hashem had actually divorced us but did not give us a get? would it mean we are still an "agunah" ( = chained, i.e. still married) to hashem?

Comment: @ninamag not entirely sure honestly -- i don't think there is a way, certainly *mideoraisa*, to divorce a woman without a *get* after *kiddushin* has taken place... one could possibly say that as Moshe broke the *luchos*, so the *kiddushin* was void frmo the original point back, as Menachem writes above -- but that totally destroys the original Maharal i quoted, not sure i am too happy about taking that route (trying to understand the Maharal's *daas* primarily)

Comment: @gt6989b did not moses send away (i.e. divorced his wife), too, but without a get? and then moses' father in law brought her back / reconciled her back to moses? something like that.

Comment: @gt6989b there are conflicting midrashim, as well as conflicting rabbinic opinions, and so one never knows really.

Comment: @ninamag the way Yalkut Shimoni learns, performing a circumcision automatically cancelled their *kiddushin* since it was done on condition of not circumsizing Gershon. The way others learn, it was not a divorce - he sent her to stay at her father's house not to put her in danger, like we would go on a business trip and leave our wives at home...

Comment: NJM and Tamir's answers there both do answer your question, no?

Comment: @RabbiKaii Actually, neither one does. NJM is not an answer, just a loose discussion on the subject. Tamir's just says G-d is not a man, which contradicts the concept in the question - many times Chazal use this analogy, and this answer basically says this analogy is nonexistent...

Comment: @gt6989b sorry, but I disagree. Tamir's answer is that it is just an analogy, but it can't be extended halachicly, which directly answers your question "can it be halachicly extended". NJM's says that in theory it would be halachicly extended, however teshuva overrides the prohibition (of having to get divorced). If these 2 answers don't answer your question, please can you rewrite the question to make it very clear what you are asking as I've read it 3 times now and I still don't see the problem. Just trying to help! Feel free to open a chat as well, and we can work on the Q together.