# When will the "marriage" between G-d and Am Yisrael be completed?

Tags: marriage, commentaries, messiah, kiddushin-eirusin, messianic-redemption

There is a Midrash that explains that this worlds serves as the "engagement of Am Yisrael with Hashem" and that the world-to-come will serve as the marriage itself. See [Yechidus, Eve of 17th of Shevat, 5745 (1985)](https://www.chabad.org/therebbe/article_cdo/aid/2513564/jewish/Yechidus-Eve-of-17th-of-Shevat-5745-1985.htm). However, the Rebbe explains that the Torah is the "bride" and Am Yisrael is the "groom".

In the [comment-section of my previous question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/131121/27180), @Dude gave a wonderful insight to this. Namely, that the "marriage" was "never completed with kiddushin and Nissuin and only the Tnai'm was made and those aspects won't be completed until Moshiach comes".

**My question is: are there any mefarshim that explain that the metaphorical marriage between Hashem and us was never completed with kiddushin and nissuin, and that that will only be the case when Moshiach comes?**

Answer (score 3):

[Midrash Rabbah Shemot 15:31](https://www.sefaria.org/Shemot_Rabbah.15.31?lang=bi):

> דָּבָר אַחֵר, הַחֹדֶשׁ הַזֶּה לָכֶם, מָשָׁל לְמֶלֶךְ שֶׁקִּדֵּשׁ
> אִשָּׁה וְכָתַב לָהּ מַתָּנוֹת מוּעָטוֹת, כֵּיוָן שֶׁבָּא לְלָקְחָהּ,
> כָּתַב לָהּ מַתָּנוֹת רַבּוֹת כְּבַעַל. כָּךְ הָעוֹלָם הַזֶּה
> אֵרוּסִין הָיוּ, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (הושע ב, כא): וְאֵרַשְׁתִּיךְ לִי
> לְעוֹלָם, וְלֹא מָסַר לָהֶם אֶלָּא הַלְּבָנָה בִּלְבָד, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר:
> הַחֹדֶשׁ הַזֶּה לָכֶם, **אֲבָל לִימוֹת הַמָּשִׁיחַ יִהְיוּ נִשֹּׂוּאִין**,
> שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (ישעיה נד, ה): כִּי בֹעֲלַיִךְ עֹשַׂיִךְ, בְּאוֹתָהּ
> שָׁעָה מוֹסֵר לָהֶן אֶת הַכֹּל, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (דניאל יב, ג):
> וְהַמַּשְׂכִּילִים יַזְהִרוּ כְּזֹהַר הָרָקִיעַ וּמַצְדִּיקֵי
> הָרַבִּים כַּכּוֹכָבִים לְעוֹלָם וָעֶד.

See also שערי רחמים, ועי' נחלת שבעה סי' ח' סעי' ח' for further reading.

Note also, that there are ma'amarot that state that Matan Torah was Chuppa (Nissuin - Kiddushin 5b) which preceded Kiddushin (see תורה אור מגילת אסתר דף צ"ח, ד)

I got the sources from these articles:

https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2836839/jewish/The-Giving-of-the-Torah-and-Jewish-Marriage-Practices.htm

https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2840619/jewish/Explanations-of-Wedding-Rituals-and-Customs-1.htm

I am also very interested in this so if you delve into these sources and find something interesting, I'd be happy to hear about it!

Hatzlacha